# Partition Sum algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, list, sum, partition

I was asked to take in a list of integers and split them into two partitions who's sums are equal. For example the list of 1 3 5 7 would be partitioned to 1+7 and 3+5. Here is the code I have so far. I am just blanking on a way faster than brute force.

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int input,n,temp,sum = 0;
   int Asum, Bsum;
   cout << "Number of inputs: ";
   cin >> n;
   cout << "Enter " << n << " numbers: ";
   int arr[n];
   int partA[n/2];
   int partB[n/2];

   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       cin >> temp;
       arr[i] = temp;
   }
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
    sum += arr[i];
   cout << sum;

   if(sum %2 !=0)
   {
       cout << "No partition";
   }
   else
   {
       sum/=2;
   }


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This can be done using Dynamic programming

Comment: Mind if I pick you brain a bit? @u_seem_surprised

Comment: We can keep the dp state as `dp[idx][sum]` to solve the question, i think i can write a recursive dp solution in c++.

Comment: @u_seem_surprised, Thanks a bunch friend. Any help is very much appreciated. If it is not too much trouble, could you maybe explain the concept a bit?

Comment: It would be hard for me to explain the concepts of dynamic programming here, I would recommend that you learn it before understanding this answer. Also the code you posted above is not correct a correct brute force would require backtracking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here i go, we can keep a dp state as `dp[idx][sum1]` where idx refers to the current index in the array and sum1 is the sum of partition 1, using these 2 parameters we can extract the third paramater that is sum2(sum2 = totalSum - sum1), which will help us reduce the no of states, rest is a straightforward recursive dp solution

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int n, arr[100], tot, dp[100][100000], mark[100];
int solve(int idx, int sum1){
    if(idx == n){
        int sum2 = tot - sum1;
        //cout << sum1 << " " << sum2 << endl;
        if(sum1 == sum2) return 1;return 0;
    }
    if(dp[idx][sum1] != -1) return dp[idx][sum1];
    int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;
    v1 = solve(idx+1, sum1);
    v2 = solve(idx+1, sum1 + arr[idx]);
    if(v1 + v2 > 0) dp[idx][sum1] = 1;
    else dp[idx][sum1] = 0;
    return dp[idx][sum1];
}

void check(int idx, int sum1){
    if(idx == n) return;
    int v1 = solve(idx+1, sum1);
    int v2 = solve(idx+1, sum1 + arr[idx]);
    if(v1 == 1){
        mark[idx] = 1;
        check(idx+1, sum1);
    }else{
        mark[idx] = 2;
        check(idx+1, sum1 + arr[idx]);
    }
}

int main(){
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0;i < n;i++) cin >> arr[i], tot += arr[i];
    memset(dp, -1, sizeof dp);
    int ct = solve(0, 0);
    if(ct == 0){
        cout << "No Partition" << endl;
    }else{
        check(0, 0);
        for(int i = 0;i < n;i++) if(mark[i] == 1) cout << arr[i] << " ";cout << endl;
        for(int i = 0;i < n;i++) if(mark[i] == 2) cout << arr[i] << " ";cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Link To Ideone : https://ideone.com/6MKLK0

Also remember that in the dp array defined, the no of indexes are 100, that means we can solve it for 100 elements, and the total sum of all those elements should not exceede 100000(which is the 2nd parameter), if you want to increase the no of elements you need to change the state, same goes for the total sum of all elements.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I will study up on this code and see Make sure I understand everything that is going on here. Thank you very much for your time.